# How to make different songs play with a play, pause, and stop button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

What I am interested in is that I have a play, stop, and pause button. Right now, I can only play one song with those buttons.

What I want to do is have an assortment of songs using buttons.

When someone clicks the button with the song they want to listen to, it starts to play, but still can be controlled by the same play, pause, and stop button.

Please forgive me if this a low-level question. I am new to Android. I have done much searching and I have seen tutorials to make a audioplayer, but that is not what I am looking for.

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mp, mp2;
    ImageButton play, pause, stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pausebutton);
        stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);

        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            setupNavigationButton();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.song1 : if(mp == null){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.joker);


        }
        mp.start();
        break;

        case R.id.playbutton : if(mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gorillaz);
        }
        mp.start();
        break;
        case R.id.pausebutton : mp.pause();break;
        case R.id.stopbutton : mp.stop(); mp = null;break;
        }
    }
    private void setupNavigationButton(){
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText( SecondActivity.this, "You Clicked it!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }





    }
```

This is my code and it runs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you want to know how to use the same button for play/pause?

Comment: Yes! For example, if I have multiple songs to choose from how do I make them play from the same play/pause button. Thank you for your response!

Comment: ok, try to use my code example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might be able to implement this with an `int[]` array. For example:

`int[] songList = {R.id.gorillaz, R.id.falloutboy, R.id.takingbacksunday, R.id.pink};`

Define this variable in `onCreate()`, and (for example), if you randomly wanted to start a new song each time, replace

```
case R.id.playbutton : if(mp == null) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gorillaz);
    }
    mp.start();
```

with

```
case R.id.playbutton : mp = null;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, songList[(int Math.random())%songList.length()]);
    mp.start();
```

where `(int Math.random())%songList.length()` is a function to generate a random integer in the range that would work with the `songList` array.

EDIT:

So based on the comments, this is my recommendation:

You will need a way to pick which song you want to play. I am going to use different buttons for each song, but you could also have a spinner to select the song and have one play/pause/stop console.

Create a button for each song. Create an onClickListener for each such like:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startSong(R.id.falloutboy); // Say this is Fall Out Boy's button
    }
}
```

where the input into `startSong()` is the id associated with the button.
Then your `startSong(int res)` method is:

```
startSong(int res) {
    if(mp == null) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, res);
    } else {
        mp.stop; 
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, res);
        mp.start;
    }
}
```

In review, you will have 1 Media Player, and each button invoke a method passing in the reference id to the song associated with that button, which will check to see if the player has been created, and if so, stop it and recreate it with the new song. Therefore, the main pause and stop buttons will affect this same Media Player.

Comment: The above is just an example (if I understood your question correctly). Make sure you change the `R.id`'s to actual resources

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I understand what you are doing and it is pretty cool. Just like an iPod shuffle haha. But, if I use an array, is it possible to assign an element of the array to a button so I can play whatever song I wanted to, when I wanted to?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to listen to Fallout Boy and I made a button for Fallout Boy. When I click that button Fallout boy starts, but I can stop the song using a universal stop, play, and pause button. If this makes sense haha.

Comment: Are you hoping for songs to play over each other? As in, you can have two different songs playing?

Comment: I don't want the songs to play over each other, but I want to change songs. For example, if I got tired of listening to Fallout Boy, I would have a button for the Gorillaz. I click on the Gorillaz button and it stops Fallout Boy and then starts the Gorillaz. Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: But, I would have  play, pause, and stop buttons that would control whatever song was selected.

Comment: Sure - you'll have to make as many "play" buttons as you songs you want. I'll update my post

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much! You are a big help. I was reading different tutorials about what I was trying to do, but I did not understand what was going on or they were way more complicated then I needed. I enjoy Android and I just really want to start small haha.

Comment: Let me know if the update makes sense/is what you were looking for

Comment: Ohh ok! Thank you for updating this and breaking it down and helping me understand the code better! This is cool, really cool! This is exactly what I am looking for too. Thank you for taking the time to help me! Like I said, I researched some of the tutorials and other sites, but I didn't have a full understanding of everything that was going on. I am trying to start small and this breaks it down well.

Comment: No problem - that's what SO is for. If this answered your question, feel free to "accept" this answer by hitting the checkmark to the left of it

Answer (score 0):

```
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
        mp.prepare();
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.song1: 
            if (mp != null)
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
            mp.prepare();
            break;
        case R.id.song2: 
            if (mp != null)
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
            mp.prepare();
            break;
        //...more songs
        case R.id.play_pause_button:
            if (mp != null)
            {
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.pause();
                    ((Button)v).setText("Play");
                }
                else
                {
                    mp.start();
                    ((Button)v).setText("Pause");
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stopbutton: 
            if (mp != null)
            {
              mp.stop(); 
              mp.release();
              mp = null;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ohhhhh I see! I didn't understand much about prepare and release, but I looked them up! This is really neat! This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!!